# Python - Controlling Tor

Tags: python, tor

I'm attempting to control Tor with Python. I've read a couple of the other questions asked about this subject on stackoverflow but none of them answer this question.

I'm looking for a method to have tor give you a 'new identity', a new IP address, when the command is run. I've googled around and found the TorCtl module as a method for controlling tor, but can't find a way to get a new identity. Here's what I have so far for atleast connecting to tor, but can't get any farther.

```
from TorCtl import TorCtl

conn = TorCtl.connect(controlAddr="127.0.0.1", controlPort=9051, passphrase="123")
```

Any help on this is appreciated, if there are other modules better then TorCtl that'd be great too! Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, out of luck I managed to find a PHP script that did the exact same thing I wanted, and with the help of that I converted it to work in TorCtl. This is what it looks like for anyone else needing it in the future!

```
from TorCtl import TorCtl

conn = TorCtl.connect(controlAddr="127.0.0.1", controlPort=9051, passphrase="123")

TorCtl.Connection.send_signal(conn, "NEWNYM")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a similar code in python:

```
def renewTorIdentity(self, passAuth):
    try:
        s = socket.socket()
        s.connect(('localhost', 9051))
        s.send('AUTHENTICATE "{0}"\r\n'.format(passAuth))
        resp = s.recv(1024)

        if resp.startswith('250'):
            s.send("signal NEWNYM\r\n")
            resp = s.recv(1024)

            if resp.startswith('250'):
                print "Identity renewed"
            else:
                print "response 2:", resp

        else:
            print "response 1:", resp

    except Exception as e:
        print "Can't renew identity: ", e
```

You can check [this post for a mini-tutorial](http://keymuck.blogspot.com/2012/02/renew-tor-identity-python-vidalia-bundle-automate-testing-website.html)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the stem package works better. You can install tor on your computer and keep it running in terminal. Then run the following program:

```
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller

with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
  controller.authenticate()
  controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
```

stem is the official package developed by tor.org, and you can see their [documentation](https://stem.torproject.org/)