# TorCtl and Socksipy library raises exception in python

Tags: python, socks, tor

I'm writing a script in python.
My script uses urllib2 to read web pages.
I'm using [Socksipy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/socksipy/) to force urllib2 to use socks proxy (TOR).
My problem is after setting `socket.socket` TorCtl doesn't work and raises exception.
the code that doesn't work is (first `newTorId()` works and second fails!):

```
  newTorId()      #This works
  import socks
  import socket
  socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "localhost", 9050)
  socket.socket = socks.socksocket
  newTorId()     #this Fails!
```

`newTorId` is defined as this:

```
from TorCtl import TorCtl
def newTorId():
    conn = TorCtl.connect(passphrase="test")
    conn.send_signal("NEWNYM")
```

The exception is:

```
__init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 97, in <module>
    newTorId()
  File "script.py", line 27, in newTorId
    conn.send_signal("NEWNYM")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_signal'
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your own code raising the exception, not the library. Particularly,

```
TorCtl.connect(passphrase="test")
```

is returning `None` the second time, resulting in an error when you call `.send_signal` on the result.

I assume `newTorId()` is intended to request a new Tor identity. You should probably just call `TorCtl.Connection.send_signal(conn, "NEWNYM")` to get a new identity, rather than trying to create a new connection each time. See [Python - Controlling Tor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911283/python-controlling-tor).

Comment: You're right about coding standards but This is not the problem (and doesn't solve it); because if each time `TorCtl.connect` should create a new object of `TorCtl.Connection` so there shouldn't be problem! (Except unclosed system sockets that i think python will close them after `newTorId()`) After that if I remove the `socket.socket = socks.socksocket` line the problem will be solved! so it seems assigning Tor to SocksiPY socket makes the problem!

Comment: I'm not talking about coding standards. Clearly `TorCtl.connect()` is returning `None`, regardless of what it "should" be doing.

Comment: Clearly ;-) You're right!! I don't know why it works in this manner but your solution works; Thanks

Comment: How does this solve the problem? `TorCtl.Connection.send_signal(conn, "NEWNYM")` relies on the same `conn` object as `conn.send_signal("NEWNYM")`. If it is `None` then both solutions won't work.

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned TorCtl's connect() method provides None if it fails to connect.

That aside, this question seems to come up pretty frequently ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17013707/how-can-i-change-my-tor-process-endpoint-in-stem), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987518/how-to-request-new-tor-identity-in-terminal)) so I just added a [FAQ entry](https://stem.torproject.org/faq.html#how-do-i-request-a-new-identity-from-tor) for it. [TorCtl is deprecated](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/torctl-deprecation-and-stem-plans), so here's an example using [stem](https://stem.torproject.org/)...

```
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller

with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
  controller.authenticate()
  controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
```