# How can I change my tor process' endpoint in stem?

Tags: python, tor

I'm using the `stem` to control a tor node created with `stem.process.launch_tor_with_config`.  I've also created a `stem.control.Controller` that is operating on the aforementioned process' control port.

How can I change the exit node?  I looked at `stem.controller.Controller.new_circuit`, but this appears to change the *intermediate* nodes, preserving the endpoint.

Does anybody know how this could be done?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

So I think I may be misunderstanding something fundamental, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.  I tried calling `Controller.get_circuits()` and found a list of `CircuitEvent` objects.  Does this mean that a single process can handle multiple circuits?  If so, how do I select one for use?

Note that I'm directing HTTP requests to through Privoxy, which in turn is forwarding it to the tor process' SOCKS port.

**Edit 2:**

I found something that works, but I don't know **how** it works, which worries me.  I'll gladly award an answer to anyone who can either:

1. Explain why my approach works
2. Show be a better approach and explain how that works

Here's what I've done:

```
for circuit in controller.get_circuits():
    controller.close_circuit(circuit.id)
```

There it is.  The external IP changed, so I know I've done *something* but hell if I know exactly what.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a couple options to use a specific exit...

- Set the ExitNodes attribute in your torrc. This is exemplified in...

https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/to_russia_with_love.html

- Call extend_circuit() on one of your present circuits to the desired endpoint...

https://stem.torproject.org/api/control.html#stem.control.Controller.extend_circuit

If the question you're trying to ask is really 'how do I get a new IP address' then that's a question we're more reluctant to answer. Partly because it's primarily for ban evasion or SEO, and partly because repeated circuit creation puts a high load on the Tor network.

As for why your IP seems to change when you call close_circuit(), that's because Tor then needs to recreate a new circuit on your behalf for the following request. There is no guarantee that the IP will be new, and doing so involves a fair bit of traffic to telescope your connection through three fresh hops.

I'm not often on StackOverflow so if you have further questions about scripting against Tor then I would suggest the tor-dev@ email list...

https://lists.torproject.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/tor-dev/

Cheers! -Damian (stem's author)

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer.  Second of all, please have my assurance that I'm not abusing the TOR network.  My goas *is*, in fact, to have some control over the endpoint IP, but I'm doing this for (what I think) is a good reason.  I'm trying to run a pool of TOR processes with various IPs to investigate some properties of the TOR network.  In other words, I'm hacking (in the constructive sense).  I hope this is okay!  With that in mind, is there a way to make a guaranteed change in endpoint IP?

Comment: Glad to hear! If you're simply looking for a pool of different exit relays then the simplest option wound probably be to find the set you want to use in atlas (http://atlas.torproject.org/), then call create_circuit() to make a circuit through each of them. The unpleasant bit is that you'll need to manually attach streams to circuits to determine 'which stream gets which IP'. See attach_stream() for this (https://stem.torproject.org/api/control.html#stem.control.Controller.attach_stream).