# New identity for TOR using c#

Tags: c#, webrequest, tor, socks

I'm using my TOR browser to connect to `.onion` websites and download data using c#. What I wanted to do, was add a button that allowed the user to get a new identity, but nothing I tried have worked so far.

I've tried using telnet, sending a webrequest to the port 9151, running a vbs that was supposed to do this, but nothing worked.

I have tried using TorSharp, but while that worked that only worked Async and I couldN't use that properly. I'm currently using `com.LandonKey.SocksWebProxy`.

How could I do this?

---

I'll add relevant code when I know what is needed, just ask.

---

EDIT:

@Ralph Wiggum

Sadly I can't remember every way I've tried creating a new Identity, as I've said, I tried running a `VBS` using `Diagnostic.Process.Start()`, but i doN'T have that script any more.

I also tried using `WebRequest` but I'm not even sure how that should be done.

This is how that looked as i can remember:

```
com.LandonKey.SocksWebProxy.Proxy.ProxyConfig pc = new com.LandonKey.SocksWebProxy.Proxy.ProxyConfig();
pc.SocksAddress = IPAddress.Parse(tb_Location.Text);
pc.SocksPort = 9151;
SocksWebProxy sw = new SocksWebProxy(pc);
HttpWebRequest wreq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://127.0.0.1");
wreq.Headers.Add("SIGNAL", "AUTHENTICATE \"\"");
wreq.Headers.Add("SIGNAL", "NEWNYM");
using (var wres = wreq.GetResponse())
{
    using (var s = new StreamReader(wres.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(s.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

I also tried using telnet (using `PrimS.Telnet`), and that didn't work either. That looked something like this:

```
CancellationToken ct = new CancellationToken(); 
PrimS.Telnet.Client c = new PrimS.Telnet.Client("127.0.0.1", 9151, ct);
c.WriteLine("AUTHENTICATE \"\"\n");
c.WriteLine("SIGNAL NEWNYM");
```

---

@drew010

As I said, I did use `TorSharp` but I stopped. It was incredibly easy to create a new identity there, but it ran entirely Async, and I couldn't manage to fix it to use it with the rest of my code.

Comment: Are you authenticated with the control socket and all that? Please post the code that you are using to connect to the control socket and create a new identity.

Comment: @WolfyD Regarding your comment about TorSharp using async for the control client, do you want the control connection to block your code until it sends the signal?  It would be fairly trivial to set up for a basic connection.  Just switch to [TcpClient.Connect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s2yca91(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of ConnectAsync and then switch the streamreader/write to use WriteLine and ReadLine instead of the async versions.  The code should be almost identical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a new identity using through code, you need to open a connection to the control port (usually 9051 and disabled by default [edit your torrc to add `ControlPort 9051`]) and issue a NEWNYM signal to establish a new circuit.

To do it you can use the [`TorControlClient`](https://github.com/joelverhagen/TorSharp/blob/master/TorSharp/Tools/Tor/TorControlClient.cs) class in TorSharp.

```
using Knapcode.TorSharp.Tools.Tor;

TorControlClient tc = new TorControlClient();
tc.ConnectAsync("localhost", 9051);
tc.AuthenticateAsync(null); // you should password protect your control connection
tc.SendCommandAsync("SIGNAL NEWNYM");
```

You can also use this [batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31758946/request-new-identity-from-windows-command-line/31765172#31765172) to request a new identity but C# is probably better for your application.  Reference that code to see the sequence on the control connection for getting a new identity.

See [ControlPort](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#ControlPort) and [HashedControlPassword](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#HashedControlPassword) configuration options.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Since editing my post I tried out the batch file solution you linked to, and that does work, thank you. It's still something outside my code so it's not really what I've wanted, but it will work untill I find a solution. Thanks!