# problem in getting new identity by tor browser in c#

Tags: c#, proxy, ip, tor

i am developing a c# project that make some request through tor browser. 
every time i want to make a request, close and reopen tor browser (in C#) to get a new IP. it works fine but when i use "SIGNAL NEWNYM" command to get new IP, my application use previous IP(instead of new IP). 
however when i rerun my application, i see that IP changed. i made a test on chrome. every time i clicked on new identity and search "what is my IP" in google chrome (or click refresh button), i see new IP in google result but when i change IP by command, i have to close chrome and reopen to see new IP(not by refresh button). what should i do to make new identity by command?

Comment: I suspect the code is using a cookie and the cookie is not changing when you select a new server.  The best way of debugging issues like this is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and check 1st request.  In your case make sure the IP address of server and cookie is different when connecting the 2nd time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tor Browser is using [Stream Isolation](https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-dev/2010-December/000680.html) to keep the exit node the same for requests to the same domain name. When using newer versions of Tor browser, `SIGNAL NEWNYM` doesn't have any effect against stream isolated connections.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56828482/892493 for more information. To get around this, you'll need to use Tor Browser's mechanism for getting a new identity. Doing that will have it change the SOCKS credentials so Tor will use a new circuit for accessing the remote site.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your IP property