# How to renew IP with Tor and stem

Tags: python-3.x, tor, stem

I'm trying to change Tor IP every 5 seconds with stem to no avail, the IP is always the same.
I mostly followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33875657/3990896) but I'm not sure if everything is setup correctly. My torrc file (windows 10) looks like this:

```
ControlPort 9051

## If you enable the controlport, be sure to enable one of these
## authentication methods, to prevent attackers from accessing it.
HashedControlPassword 16:05834BCEDD478D1060F1D7E2CE98E9C13075E8D3061D702F63BCD674DE
```

And I need Tor Browser opened for the code below to work, is that normal or it's a sign of some misconfiguration?

```
import requests
import time    
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller

# signal TOR for a new connection
def changeIP():
    with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
        controller.authenticate(password="password")
        controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
        print("IP switched")

# new tor session
tor_session = requests.session()
tor_session.proxies = {}
tor_session.proxies['http'] = 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9150'
tor_session.proxies['https'] = 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9150'

for i in range(5):
    # check IP from tor session
    r = tor_session.get('http://httpbin.org/ip')
    print(r.text)
    time.sleep(5)
    changeIP()
```

Comment: You might try stream isolation as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56828482/892493) instead.

Comment: Thanks @drew010, got it to work with stream isolation.