# Selenium: Change Tor circuit

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tor

I have a Selenium script that controls a Tor browser. However, I'm unable to use the functionality 'New Tor Circuit for this site' even by sending the Ctrl+Shift+L combination to the browser.

Can someone explain how I can achieve this?

For reference, I'm using C# with the OpenQA Selenium package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "new circuit" is a Tor Browser behaviour, you can't "launch" it with Selenium, Selenium just acts on the viewport.

But you can anyway launch a terminal command programmatically.

[Take a look here](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/fortran/tor+new+identity+command+line)

or there: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31758946/request-new-identity-from-windows-command-line)

Comment: this is for launching a new identity, could you please provide the code to change circuit? and the windows command if possible

Comment: One more thing, this doesn't seem to work on certain sites whilst the 'Change tor circuit for this site' button does. Is there any further functionality I need to add?

Comment: No, I just get OK responses from the control port. I suspect it has something to do with the circuit being marked as dirty but not being terminated, if that makes sense?

Comment: #NumX i don't think so...i'm sorry but i can't do more than this, i've not completely understood what's happening